# how to run an application in c++ and write to its stdin and read from its stdout in windows

Tags: c++, process

I want to run an application in c++ and read its stdout and write t stdin in windows? No popup should be generated.

Can I do it easily using windows services?

I found that I maybe able to do this with POCO, but do I really need this?

Is there solution in std library for this?

Comment: By "popup" you mean a command prompt window? Using `stdin` and `stdout` is a lot more difficult if you don't write the code in console mode, but can be done - although standard library doesn't really support it at all well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can spawn a child process and then gain access to its stdin and stdout pipes. You have to use WinAPI to achieve this. See example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499(v=vs.85).aspx

You may use Qt and it's QProcess class to read/write child process output/input.